# App started crashing after upgrading app targetSDK to 32

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, dependency-management, targetsdkversion

I've upgraded my app target SDK 30 to 32, after updating created the release build & installed the builds over the older build(In short, I update the app on the device).
Now,app started crashing after this update & getting the following crash logs.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
                            Process: com.zerion.apps.iform.main, PID: 7750
                            java.lang.VerifyError: Superclass c.a of c.g is declared final (declaration of 'c.g' appears in /data/app/~~B1TWx2zBH9lfzsGOMr146Q==/com.zerion.apps.iform.main-MzBcSg49f0sTgamcKa69Ag==/base.apk!classes2.dex)
                                at j$.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.<clinit>(Unknown Source:35)
                                at com.zerionsoftware.iformdomainsdk.domain.logging.LogMessageGenerator.createMessage(SourceFile:1)
                                at com.zerionsoftware.iformdomainsdk.data.retrofit.LoggingInterceptor.intercept(SourceFile:5)
                                at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(SourceFile:10)
                                at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(SourceFile:1)
                                at com.zerionsoftware.iformdomainsdk.data.retrofit.NetworkConnectionInterceptor.intercept(SourceFile:3)
                                at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(SourceFile:10)
                                at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(SourceFile:1)
                                at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(SourceFile:13)
                                at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(SourceFile:2)
                                at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(SourceFile:3)
                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
```

I'm working on this issue so long, but unable to find the exact problem.

Comment: Superclass c.a of c.g is declared final (declaration of 'c.g' appears in /data/app/~~B1TWx2zBH9lfzsGOMr146Q==/com.zerion.apps.iform.main-MzBcSg49f0sTgamcKa69Ag==/base.apk!classes2.dex)

This line seems to be obfuscated due to R8/Progaurd, you can try to figure out what code is present at this line of the stack trace.
                                at com.zerionsoftware.iformdomainsdk.domain.logging.LogMessageGenerator.createMessage(SourceFile:1)

Comment: so you are not getting the same crash in debug build right? then I think you should once again verify if all the required proguard rules are added to your project and also check if any of the libraries added need an update. I came across like a same situation.

Comment: @AnkitWala Yes, Have checked the code & that is java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter class I'm using to parse the string to Date. which is causing the crash. Any idea how to fix?